# How to implement a three-input LUT if I have a lot of two-input LUTs?

Tags: fpga, verilog, multiplexer

I have gone through various sources... But I am not quite sure what it is.

For example, I have three input variables: A, B and C. Now I have to use two 2-input LUTs such that their input lines are connected to variables A and B. Then connect their outputs to a 2x1 multiplexer whose select line is the input variable C.

But in this problem, I'm not allowed to use the MUX, only two 2-input LUTs. How can it be?

The configuration of LUTs would depend upon the particular Boolean function that you wish to realise. Can you cite an example, please?

Comment: Try giving A and B as inputs to LUT1, then send the output of LUT1 and C to the inputs of LUT2. You may need to change whether A, B, or C is the one in the second stage depending on the function. I'm not sure if all boolean functions can be made in this way, or just some of them.

Answer (score 5):

A 3-input LUT is an 8-bit memory, and that memory can contain one of 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 different values. Each value represents one possible Boolean function of the three input variables.

A 2-input LUT can contain one of 2<sup>4</sup> = 16 different functions.

When you cascade two 2-input LUTs, you are effectively creating a temporary variable T that is a function of two of the inputs (16 choices) and then the final output is a function of T and the third input (16 more choices), for a total of 32 choices. Since you get to pick which of the three input variables is connected to the second LUT, you can actually create up to 32 × 3 = 96 different functions this way.

However, this leaves 256 - 96 = 160 functions that cannot be created. These additional functions require a true 3-input LUT, or two 2-input LUTs plus a mux.

It's easy to construct such a function — a function that requires two different 2-input LUTs. For example, suppose you want A AND B when C is high, but A OR B when C is low:

$$Y = ABC + (A+B)\overline{C} = ABC + A\overline{C}+B\overline{C}$$

There's no way to decompose this into two functions of two variables each. If you look at the 3-D Karnaugh map of this function, you'll gain some insight as to why.

If all you have is 2-input LUTs, you'll need to use three of them to create a 2:1 mux, and then two more to hold your 8 function bits, for a total of five 2-input LUTs to emulate a general-purpose 3-input LUT.

If you are given

$$Y = f(A, B, C)$$

The five 2-input LUTS are

$$S = f(A, B, 0)$$
$$T = f(A, B, 1)$$
$$U = S \cdot \overline{C}$$
$$V = T \cdot C$$
$$Y = U + V$$

Here's the same thing in the form of a diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fat7ns.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I find your terminology of LUT different than what I've learned; a LUT is a Look Up Table, so a 3 input table would have 3 address lines and thus 8 values.  In addition the LUT words can be any size from 1 to n, so a 3 input LUT table could represent an 8 values of 32 bits for example.
So I don't understand your derivation of how a 2 input function could contain one of 24 = 16 different functions?
Are the variables A,B,C,S,T single bit variables or multibit variables?

Comment: In the context of FPGAs, a LUT is strictly 1 bit wide, and generates a single Boolean function.

Comment: Can you send me, please, a circuit of scheme ?

Comment: Seriously, you need to do at least *some* of the work on this yourself. If I hold your hand the whole way, you won't actually retain any of this.

Comment: Thank you very much )

Comment: I have some problems with my software opportunity, and in this moment I can't drawing.

But I need circuit, that is my problem.

Comment: There's always paper and pencil. But to be honest, it isn't clear to me what you need a drawing of. The two-LUT configuration? The five-LUT configuration? Something else?

Comment: The five-LUTs configuration and how do you make a 2:1 mux using three 2-input LUTs ?

Comment: Check my circuit, please !

Comment: @Dave I have problem in understanding the reasoning about the number of functions can be represented by cascading two 2-input LUTs: suppose that the 3 inputs are A, B, C, and A, B are inputs for the 1st LUT, and C is one of the input for the 2nd LUT. As each LUT has 4 bits to be programmed for a function, then there are totally 4*2=8 bits in two LUTs to be programmed for a function....and 8 bits correspond to 256 different functions...what's wrong with my reasoning? Thanks!

Comment: @bruin: I think I explained it fairly well above, but here's another try: You can treat the two 4-bit LUTs as a single 8-bit memory only if you have a multiplexer to combine their outputs based on the third input bit -- each combination of the three input values selects one bit from the LUTs. If you just cascade them, you cannot generate all 256 unique functions, because one of the address bits to the second LUT is a **single** function of two of the inputs -- you cannot implement a function that can't be decomposed in this fashion.

Comment: @Dave got it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There's always paper and pencil...

[image]

Comment: This is correct.